# A tuple is not defined, but it contains information

Tags: python, module, tuples

I am looking a module ifcopenshell, and I see a very weird function:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import functools
import numbers
import itertools
from . import ifcopenshell_wrapper
try:
    import logging
except ImportError as e:
    logging = type('logger', (object,), {'exception': staticmethod(lambda s: print(s))})
class entity_instance(object):
    def __init__(self, e):
        if isinstance(e, tuple):
            e = ifcopenshell_wrapper.new_IfcBaseClass(*e)
        super(entity_instance, self).__setattr__('wrapped_data', e)
```

In this case, `tuple` is not explicitly defined anywhere, but it contains a value. My assumption is that `tuple` comes from an import. Is that right? How can I track where `tuple` came from?

here is commenten of function isininstance:

Definition : isinstance(o: object, t: Union[type, Tuple[Union[type, Tuple[Any, ...]], ...]], /) -> bool
Return whether an object is an instance of a class or of a subclass thereof.
A tuple, as in isinstance(x, (A, B, ...)), may be given as the target to check against. This is equivalent to isinstance(x, A) or isinstance(x, B) or ... etc.

Comment: I can't tell what your question is.  What tuple are you asking about?

Comment: [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) is a  built-in, like `print` or `int`. It's available in all modules by default.

Comment: How can a tuple that's not defined contain information?

Comment: @defladamouse i am telling the tuple of isinstance function

Comment: @Brian but isinstance function will compare e and tuple, wether e is contained in tuple. And default tuple is empty. So function isinstance will never be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) is a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) *type*, like `int` and `str`. Try it for yourself:

```
>>> x = (3, 4)
>>> tuple
<class 'tuple'>
>>> isinstance(x, tuple)
True
>>> isinstance(x, str)
False
```

Comment: i was confuesed by commenten of  function isinstance and think it must have some information in it.