# What data should I pass to this constructor?

Tags: python, module

I am trying to use function **init** to creat a new entify.
But i dont know what "e" should i give. "e" must be a tuple. But how can i know what it looks like?

```
class entity_instance(object):
    def __init__(self, e):
        if isinstance(e, tuple):
            e = ifcopenshell_wrapper.new_IfcBaseClass(*e)
        super(entity_instance, self).__setattr__('wrapped_data', e)
```

here is function new_IfcBaseClass:

```
def new_IfcBaseClass(schema_identifier, name):
"""new_IfcBaseClass(std::string const & schema_identifier, std::string const & name) -> entity_instance"""
    return _ifcopenshell_wrapper.new_IfcBaseClass(schema_identifier, name)
```

here is my main code:

```
import ifcopenshell
from ifcopenshell import entity_instance
ifc=ifcopenshell.open('file.ifc')
Object = entity_instance()
entity_instance.__init__(('#1','ifctoken'))
```

I gave a random tuple to test, wether i can build a new entify_instance. but i get "**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'"as Error message.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to pass a tuple?

Comment: Well, where does `ifcopenshell_wrapper.new_IfcBaseClass` come from? Did you try *reading the documentation*? There's no way we can tell you anything about this code, because you have not shown us and we have no way to know where it comes from.

Comment: It looks like you tried to [ask this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327399/a-tuple-is-not-defined-but-it-contains-information). It was unclear before what you were trying to do, and even less clear now.

Comment: @mkrieger I tried to use a random tuple. And I get "__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e' " as error

Comment: Please show a [mre] of the code you have tried.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use IfcOpenShell, but the question you're asking is about a problem you probably shouldn't be having in the first place. Please explain what you're actually trying to do, which is causing the error you're asking about - this is an XY problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel    It's an another question. All i am trying to do is to build a new Entify. The problem right now is I need to know what kind of tuple should i give as input to get a entify. Its that possible by Entify， that already exists， to know what this Tuple looks like.

Comment: @Grismar I am trying to build a new ifctype to do my research, just like ifcwall, ifcdoor. I already find this entify_instance is for all ifc class. But i need a tuple as input to use it. how can i know what it looks like? can i use ifctype that already exist to know what it looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `__init__` directly. It's a 'dunder' (referring to the double underscores on either side) or 'magical' (referring to the fact that they add behaviour that just 'magically' works without actually called it) method.

`__init__` is called when you instantiate an object, so your code would be:

```
import ifcopenshell
from ifcopenshell import entity_instance
ifc=ifcopenshell.open('file.ifc')
Object = entity_instance(('#1','ifctoken'))
```

I didn't actually test this, as I have no .ifc files (or ifcopenshell installed), but since your problem is more of a generic Python issue, I'm fairly certain this is at least part of your problem.

Note that I didn't change the naming, but `Object` would be an exceedingly bad choice for a variable - the capital 'O' suggests it's actually a class (when it is an instance) and 'object' is about as generic as it gets - and even then `object` would be an extremely bad choice as it shadows the `object` super type in Python.

Comment: thank u for ur informative answer!